# How to Send Collection View Cell Text via Segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, segue

I am trying to send a label that is contained within a collection view cell to another view controller with a segue.

My plan is that when a user taps on the collection view cell, the app then segues to the next view controller where the navigation bar's title displays the text of the label in the collection view cell selected.

I have tried this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CCCollectionViewCell

    //itemSelected = items[indexPath.row] as String

    itemSelected = cell.pLabel.text!

    print(itemSelected)
}
```

and in prepareForSegue I have not written any code as I am not sure how this works.

I commented out the block '..items[indexPath.row] as String' because it won't show the label and added the print function to see what will output but it only outputs the name given in the storyboard.

I am very new to Xcode so am not familiar with didSelect and prepareForSegue. All I am trying to do is to send the text within a collection view cell to another view controller with a segue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your code you are not calling the `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` so you probably have created segue from the CollectionViewCell to `DestinationViewController`. So get the indexPath using this cell in `prepareForSegue` method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

     if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell, 
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) {

         let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController //Cast with your DestinationController
         //Now simply set the title property of vc
         vc.title = items[indexPath.row] as String
     }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "contentVideoSegue", sender: indexPath)

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "contentVideoSegue"{
        let selectedIndexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath
        let videoContentVC = segue.destination as! VideoContentController
        videoContentVC.text = items[selectedIndexPath.row] as String
    }
}
```

in the hope of helping :)

Comment: please add some description explaining the answer

Comment: Firstly in the didSelectItemAt indexPath method is calling sugue. After this call override func prepare(for segue) method starts to work. @jjj

Answer (score 0):

So you don't need to set up the cell in didSelect because you're already doing that in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Rather you'll want to call `performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueName", sender: indexPath)` in your didSelectItemAtIndexPath. Then in your prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    guard let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath else { return }

    let collectionCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    let textToPass = collectionCell.textLabel.text

    let detailVC = segue.destination as? DetailViewController
    detailVC.passedInString = textToPass
}
```